# Max\min of $f(x, y, z) = x^3+y^2+z^2$ on the set given by a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find max and min (if they exist) of the following function:
$f(x, y, z)  = x^3+y^2+z^2$

On the set $C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$

I have checked that the Lagrange theorem assumptions hold, so that I can find the critical points solving the following system

$3x^2-2x\lambda z=0$

$2y-2y\lambda=0$

$2z-2z\lambda=0$

$\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)=0$

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$

Then I found the critical points $x_1=(0,0,0)$, $x_2=(0,y,z)$ s.t. $y^2+z^2=1$, $x_3=(x,0,z)$ s.t $x^2+z^2=1$,$x_4=(x,y,0)$ s.t $x^2+y^2=1$. Clearly the constrain set is compact so that the function f has a min and max in it. However how do I evaluate the function f at $x_4=(x,y,0)$ s.t $x^2+y^2=1$ or $x_3=(x,0,z)$ s.t $x^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: $$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad|x|\leq1\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad x^3\leq x^2\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad x^3+y^2+z^2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1.$$

Comment: Also, $$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \text{ and } |x| \leq 1\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad -x^2\leq x^3\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad -1 \leq -x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq x^3+y^2+z^2 $$

Comment: There is also a maximum along the circle $\{0,\zeta,\pm\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\},\ \ \ -1\le \zeta < 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first look for critical points in the interior. This is not about Lagrange multipliers: you just look for the partial derivatives to be zero. That is, 
$$
3x^2=0, \ \ 2y=0,\ \ \ 2z=0. 
$$
So the only critical point on the interior is $(0,0,0)$.

On the boundary, you apply Lagrange multipliers under the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. You get the system 
$$
\begin{array}
3x^2=2\lambda x\\ 
2y(1-\lambda)=0\\
2z(1-\lambda)=0\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1
\end{array}
$$
We split in some cases

- $x=0$. This satisfies the first equation. From the fourth one we get that at least one of $y,z$ is not zero; so $\lambda=1$ and all points $(0,y,z)$ with $y^2+z^2=1$.
- $x\ne0$. The first equation is $3x=2\lambda$. This gives us subcases depending on $\lambda$:
- $\lambda=1$. This gives $x=2/3$, and we are free two choose $y,z$ according to the fourth equation: so we have critical points $(\tfrac23,y,z)$ with $y^2+z^2=1-\tfrac49=\tfrac59$.
- $\lambda\ne1$. This gives $y=z=0$, and so $x=\pm1$. Critical points $(\pm1,0,0)$.

Now you evaluate your function on the critical points:

- $f(0,y,z)=y^2+z^2=1$ in the first case.
- $f(\tfrac23,y,z)=\left(\tfrac23\right)^3+y^2+z^2=\left(\tfrac23\right)^3+\tfrac59=\tfrac{23}{27}$ in the second case.
- $f(1,0,0)=1$, $f(-1,0,0)=-1$ in the last case.

The interior contributes $f(0,0,0)=0$. So the maximum is $1$ and the minimum is $-1$.